# How can I force swap to use all of my BTRFS swap file?

Tags: btrfs, swap

I created a BTRFS swap file using the following command:

```shellsession
$ btrfs filesystem mkswapfile -s 8G SwapFile
```

However, swap only uses 1GB of the swap file, as shown by the following command sequence:

```shellsession
$ du -csh SwapFile ; free
8.0G    SwapFile
8.0G    total
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        12148108     5915736     1232604      743948     6132596     6232372
Swap:        1048572       35576     1012996
```

Is there some quota thing or similar option that I could use to force the Linux swap mechanism to use all of the BTRFS swap file I created?

Comment: Could you add the output of `swapon --summary`?

Comment: Info provided by swapon --summary is almost exactly the same as provided by free: "home/zSwapVol/SwapFile                 file            1048572         35576           -2"

Swap file is on a separate swap volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [reported bug](https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/issues/568). Since according to the [manual](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-filesystem.html) `mkswapfile` is a simplified version of mkswap, what you can do after you create the file is run mkswap:

```
# mkswap SwapFile
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. After running `swapoff` followed by the above command, `free` and `htop` now sees the full 8GB. I'm curious, however, if the procedure I followed has any risks (that is, I didn't delete my current swap file but just disabled it temporarily).

Comment: You turned it off, so everything in there was moved to main memory or another swap. Then you reformatted it and readded it. It's ok. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned bug has been fixed in version 6.1.3 of the btrfs-progs, see https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/milestone/82?closed=1

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. If possible, please add a link to the relevant release notes or changelog for further reference.